# dataframe duplicate with conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

ok, I have a bit of a humdinger.

I hava a dataframe that can be upwards of 120,000 entries

The frames will be similar to this:

```
ID        UID     NAME       DATE
1        1234     Bob        02/02/2020
2        1235     Jim        02/04/2020
3        1234     Bob        
4        1234     Bob        02/02/2020
5        1236     Jan        20/03/2020
6        1235     Jim
```

I need to be able to eliminate all duplicates, however; i need to check if in the duplicates, if there is a date, then that one, or one of the ones that does have a date, is the one kept, and remove all others. if there is no date in any of the duplicates, then just use whichever is easiest.

I am struggling to come up with a way to do this elegantly.
My thought is:
iterate through all entries, for each entry, create a temp DF and place all duplicates in it, iterate through THAT df and if i find a date, save the index and then delete each entry that is not that entry.. but that seems VERY bulky and slow.
any better suggestions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the blanks are empty string `''`, you can do this:

```
(sample_df.sort_values(['UID','NAME','DATE'], 
                       ascending=(True, True, False))
          .groupby(['UID','NAME'])
          .first()
          .reset_index())
```

which gives you:

```
    UID     NAME    DATE
0   1234    Bob     02/02/2020
1   1235    Jim     02/04/2020
2   1236    Jan     20/03/2020
```

Note the `ascending` flag in `sort_values`. Pandas will sort string according to their length, and to have non-empty `DATE` sorted before empty `DATE` (i.e. `''`), you need to sort the column in descending order.

After sorting, you can simply group each pair of `(UID, NAME)` and keep the first entry.

Comment: sorry, they are not Nan, they are ''

Comment: so, if i sort using the example above, then do a drop_duplicate and keep the first entry, this should work?